# Transformations.switchMap Function not called in ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, switchmap

I am observer LiveData from Repository and transform to view,here Transformations.switchMap Function not called in ViewModel. If I use observeForEver it works good.

```
Transformations.switchMap(signInResponseMutableLiveData){signInResponse ->
            val mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<Any>()

            if (signInResponse is FirebaseUser) {
                val firebaseUserEmail = signInResponse.email

                homeFragmentUIDataLiveData.value = HomeFragmentUIData(firebaseUserEmail ?: "")
            } else if (signInResponse is String) {
                loginErrorEventLiveData.value = signInResponse
            }

            mutableLiveData
        }
```

Comment: Actually it is available in ViewModel class and observes LiveData from Repository and update data to UI. switchMap should return LiveData thats the reason using dummy LiveData.My main aim is update homeFragmentUIDataLiveData and loginErrorEventLiveData which are observed in Fragment.

Comment: To transform data from one LiveData to another LiveData

Comment: observe method needs LifecycleOwner but I need to call from ViewModel

Comment: If use observeForever  we should remove observer manully, then what is the use of using Architecture components? I think something missing in switchMap,because I already implemented this pattern in java and it works great. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html#observeForever(android.arch.lifecycle.Observer%3CT%3E)

Comment: Even it is used inside switchMap, we don't need to do it manually.That is the reason to avoid common mistakes.

Comment: Okay I use switchMap

Comment: have you found a solution?